# ASP.NET Core DI - Inject *only for* the dependency tree of a certain type

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I'm trying to configure ASP.NET DI to a certain behavior and I'm having trouble finding documentation to cover my specific case.

**TL;DR**: I have multiples implementations of a certain interface `IBar`. Multiple classes depend on it, but each class should receive a different implementation. How can I do it?

---

Let's say I have a class `Foo` that depends on a service `IBar`. Now, `IBar` is pretty generic, and can be used in multiple places, so maybe I also have `Baz` and `Qux` depending on `IBar`.

I have a very specific implementation of `IBar`, called FooBar, that I want to be injected on instances of `Foo`, but not on instances of `Baz` or `Qux`. *Preferrably*, I would also want that any dependency of `Foo` that requires a `IBar` also get `FooBar`, but that's not a big requirement.

I know I can do it very manually by registering a factory to `Foo` and them, inside the factory, use reflection to obtain ctors, and try to resolve them one by one by using the `IServiceProvider` and injecting `IBar` whenever the required ctor parameter is of that type --- thing is, this approach is like reimplementing a big part of the DI container, which I think is abominable. And if I want to be *transitive* about this (the preferred behavior above), I would have to reimplement all the logic scanning and building each type.

What I believe should be possible is something like using the container to create a derived/child container, register `FooBar` to it and just resolve `Foo`.

Comment: You say Baz depends on IBar but shouldn't receive one. How does this square? Maybe a less abstract example or code would help.

Comment: @NoahStahl It should receive an IBar implementation, but not the same that Foo should receive.

Comment: You will most likely have to segregate those interfaces and have your classes depend on their specific derived interface/implementation. The default .Net Core DI is a basic container and does not easily satisfy your requirements. There are however my robust DI container that extend the DI container. You could try looking into those to see if they can satisfy your scenario. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines#default-service-container-replacement

Comment: @Nkosi is right. Take a look at Autofac, which I have used multiple times to implement your exact use case.

Comment: But that said, I agree with Nkosi and Abdusco, MS.DI contains no functionality to implement context-based injection. You will either have to change your design to fit MS.DI, or switch to a different DI Container.

Comment: Thanks @Steven. I don't really want to customize the DI to make this work. Thanks a lot for your insights.